# Does Oracle cache sql statements as the same if the variables are different?

Tags: sql, oracle, caching, binding, parameters

I was wondering if I wrote code, so it produced two sql statements that were the same, but the variable names where different would they be cached as the same statement?

For example if I had:

```
Select * from example where id in (:inarg0, inarg1);
Select * from example where id in(:inarg2, inarg3);
```

**Update:**
I made a function that will take an array of data and convert it to binded variables that increment up every time the function is called. This great to have sql injection. I was just hoping I could gain some performance from it as well, by having the statement be cached. Positional bind variables isn’t an option because the function mixes in with other bindable variables like

`Select * from example where name = :name and expt = (:inarg0, inarg1) and date=:todaysDate and loc in (:inarg2, :inarg3, :inarg4)`

If the function was to run again in the same program however it’d look like this:

```
Select * from example where name = :name and expt = (:inarg5, inarg6) and date=:todaysDate and loc in (:inarg7, :inarg8, :inarg9)
```

Comment: How, exactly, are you producing the two SQL statements?  Are these bind variables?  SQL*Plus substitution variables?  Or something else?  What do you mean by "cache" (i.e. are you talking about avoiding a hard parse or a soft parse?  Avoiding creating a child cursor?).  And what version of Oracle?  It's a seemingly simple question but there is a lot of complexity buried there depending on exactly what you are doing and exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I am producing this statement with c#. I take an array of data and it makes an sql statement that has a variable for each data element and then binds each element to that variable. There can be more then just in statement variables too, so I can't use positional.

Comment: Is it safe, then, to assume that you may have different numbers of bind variables?  It seems unlikely that you would be in a situation where your array always has exactly two data elements.  Are you saying that you have a variable number of bind variables outside the `IN` list as well?  And what sort of "cache" are you worried about on the Oracle side?

Comment: I've made an update with more examples. The bind variables that are not in the in statement will always be the same amount of variables. The in statements can be dynamic in size but it's more likely it's closer to 2 or 3 than more than that. I'm wondering if for some reason the variable names are different but the data for the variables are the same would this be cached and not have to hit the tables again?

Comment: OK.  And exactly what sort of caching are you talking about?  Are you asking whether Oracle would do a hard parse or a soft parse of the second SQL statement?  Whether it would use any blocks from the table that are still in the buffer cache?  Whether it would execute the second SQL statement or just return the data from the first?  Or something else?

Comment: both. Would it do a hard or soft parse? (I'm assuming hard?) and will it use the same blocks of data in buffer or not. (Hopefully it uses the same blocks in buffer?)

Comment: In military terms, you're Fighting The Last War.  Unless your real statements are far more complex than the examples you've shown the parse time is insignificant - I/O time will completely swamp the parse time.  Remember: the best time to optimize is never.  The second best time is when you have a measureable performance problem.  The WORST time is when you *think* you *might* have a problem *in a particular place* *someday*.  If you can't measure it, there is **no problem**, in which case there's **nothing to optimize**.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: The function that is used for the in statement is for somewhere around 1000 different sql statements that range anywhere from as simple as the one above to 15 joined tables. Since this function covers such a broad scope of my program I wanted to make sure that it is as good as it can be. Since it wouldn't take much work to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It will be treated as different queries - parsed queries won't be reused. To test it, execute both queries and verify corresponding lines in v$sql. You are doing things similar to cursor_sharing=force parameter value - except that Oracle does a better job with variable names - to make them easier for SQL reuse.